# What can we say about the convergence of this series

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$\sum {z^n\over n!} $$

I used Alembert's Ration test and get $$\lim_{n \infty}{u_n\over u_{n+1}}={n+1\over z}$$ As this tends to $\infty>1$ can i say that the given series is convergent for all values of $z$ ?

*Note : z is a complex number*

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A good thing to remind is the proof of this property, which in your case writes:

$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \frac z{n+1}
\implies 
\left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right| \le 1/2 <1
$$when $n$ is big enough, and then
$$
|u_n| \le C2^{-n}
$$for every $n$, for a certain $C>0$. Hence the series is (absolutely) convergent.

Comment: The problem is actually a part of a problem from complex analysis. It says that the given series is convergent for $|z|<\infty$ , is it just to avoid $\infty / \infty$

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong. The D'Alemebert Ratio test considers
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}
$$
NOT
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{u_{n}}{u_{n+1}}
$$

so correct limit to consider is
$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{z}{n+1}\stackrel{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\;\;\;\forall z\in\mathbb C
$$

Hence your power series converges on the whole complex plane.

To be precise: the series converges to a well known entire function: actually we have that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}=e^z\;\;\;\forall z\in\mathbb C.
$$

Answer (score -1):

The summation of the given series can be given as $e^z$ and hence the given series is convergent.

Comment: Do you really think this is the subject here?

Comment: The first part is true, the second part is restating the question.

Comment: I do not understand the "recommend deletion" votes here. It *is* an attempt to answer the question, albeit not really correct. Surely downvoting is the correct response here, not voting to delete!